# Can I export objects from Pharo into a file?

Tags: json, pharo

I have written a small key/value database in Instantiations VAST using the inbuilt ObjectDumper and ObjectLoader classes. As I need to move to a Mac, I am getting to grips with Pharo and would like to do the same type of operation. Rather than use a proprietary file format (as with VAST), I would like to export aJSON and import it back as and when.

Lets say
| myObject |

myObject objectName: 'Test';
objectValue: '£1.23'.
myObject exportToJSON

Can anyone give me some clues as too how I would implement this?

David

Answer (score 1):

The simple proprietary way is using Fuel, that is built-in. That is smart enough to deal with object cycles. See FLSerializer and FLMaterializer. NeoJSON indeed provides the tools for you to create the mappings. STONJSON is even simpler for limited object graphs